# Excel 2013 change result of preset formula in a column of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created an Excel workbook for my client to paste the data which are copied from a system for preparing reports.

However, there is a critical column of data format being changed after copying and pasting data from system to that Excel worksheet on my client's terminal.

I have written a formula on column P `=TEXT(G1,"mmm"&"-"&"yy")` to capture the date info and make it as a text `MMM-YY` from the pasted data field G. The data of column data A to N is used for pasting the data.

[image]

No matter how I do, no matter locking cells and protect sheet. It couldn't help

By the way, It works fine on my terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have asked my client to correct the terminal short date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is your machine's date format. Probably, you are using *D/M/YYYY* format while your data is using *M/D/YYYY*. You can see that dates in G and L column are left-aligned, however Excel default for dates are right-aligment like numbers.

You should parse the day, month and year first and then convert them to date. Please check the formulas at below. They assumes the date is at *A2* cell.

```
            First /         Second /              Day               Month                   Year                      Date
5/22/1992   =FIND("/",$A2)  =FIND("/",$A2,B2+1) =LEFT($A2,B2-1) =MID($A2,B2+1,C2-B2-1)  =RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-C2) =DATE($F2,$E2,$D2)
```

The link below provides detailed information: [How to convert D/M/YYYY date to M/D/YYYY](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-convert-d-m-yyyy-date-to-m-d-yyyy-date-or-vice-versa/)